# How to Fetch Data in ManyToMany Django And render in view.py

Tags: django

I want to fetch Data to my view.py where the buyer select a specific market. Which Means the Buyer can only see the Market he selects.

```
class Market(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.TextField("Market Address")
    interval = models.PositiveIntegerField("Market Day Interval", default=5)
    startdate = models.DateField("Initial Date", auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False) 
    location = models.ForeignKey(Local, related_name='market_location', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    desciption = models.TextField("Good Description")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Buyer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    market = models.ManyToManyField(Market, related_name='interested_markets')
    status = models.BooleanField("User Status", default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

view.py

```
@login_required
@buyer_required
def welcome_buyer(request): 
    buyer = request.user.buyer
    market = buyer.interested_markets.all()


    return render(request, 'buyer/home.html', {
    'market': market
    })
```

Comment: what issue are you facing

Comment: I buyer has option to pick more that one market during regsitration. I want to pick all market that the buyer picked.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply iterate over this using your buyer object:

```
for market in buyer.market_set.all()
```

or

```
markets = buyer.market_set.all()
```

in your case it would be:

```
markets = buyer.interested_markets_set.all()
```

or

```
markets = buyer.market # you should consider changing it's name to be plural to indicate that it's a list of objects like: buyer.markets
```

for more details read the docs here: [django many to many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: AttributeError at /buyers/buyer/

'Buyer' object has no attribute 'market_set'

Comment: i think you named it interested_markets, then it would be interested_markets_set

Comment: AttributeError at /buyers/buyer/

'Buyer' object has no attribute 'interested_markets_set'

Comment: i think buyer.market might work for you in this case. it will return list of markets related to a buyer